# I am getting an error httpd dead subsys locked

Tags: linux, apache, fedora

I  am new in linux administration . I want to host multiple site but i am always getting a error httpd dead subsys locked .

Comment: check the http status using another user (root), or run this "sudo service httpd status"

Answer (score 5):

http://awaseroot.wordpress.com/2012/06/11/subsys-lock-problem-with-centos-6-2-and-apache/ Kill the httpd process, check the pid file in httpd.conf and then restart httpd this link gives you a detailed insight.

Answer (score 5):

A kinda common issue with Apache server. Since you have not mentioned your exact Linux OS generalised answer would be enough.

The first thing we need to check "**httpd service**" is running in another process of a different user.

check the http status using another user (root), or run this

```
sudo service httpd status
```

You may get the error "**httpd dead but subsys locked**"

Then,

Try to delete lock file

```
sudo rm -f /var/lock/subsys/httpd
```

If it **FAILED**

The kill the process

```
killall -9 httpd
```

Remove the lock file

```
sudo rm -f /var/lock/subsys/httpd
```

Restart the service

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain what this error is about? Why is it a common occurance?

Answer (score 2):

Check your disk space using `df -h`. If you have a full disk, it can cause this error.